# Scala plugin could not be installed on Intellij, Read timed out error?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, plugins

I am trying to install Scala on IntelliJ, but getting the following error:[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I can however download the **zip** file and install the plugin manually. Is it some proxy issue? I could not figure it out.

Comment: Almost impossible to say given the minimal information you've presented, but I'd say since you can download it manually, a proxy issue seems lkely, yes.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul There is nothing present in the proxy settings, not sure what is happening. It is an ultimate edition so sent an email to the support.

Comment: Do you have a proxy set up system-wide (e..g for IE?) If so, **not** having a proxy in IntelliJ may be the issue.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Nope. I don't have any other proxy setting. I checked the bash file and everything.